# Why I got errors running redis in laravel app?

Tags: laravel, redis

I need to run laravel 5 app on my local Kubuntu 18 and I need to run redis server for this app

I installed and in file /etc/redis/redis.conf I uncommented line :

```
requirepass foobared
```

in .env I modified redis config :

```
REDIS_HOST=http://127.0.0.1:8000  # I run app with command :  php artisan serve  
REDIS_PASSWORD=foobared
REDIS_PORT=6379 # default port
```

I restarted redis and check status:

```
$ sudo service redis status
[sudo] password for serge: 
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-02-26 13:52:09 EET; 6min ago
     Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
           man:redis-server(1)
  Process: 1545 ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1548 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1574 (redis-server)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
           └─1574 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379

Feb 26 13:52:08 AtHome systemd[1]: Starting Advanced key-value store...
Feb 26 13:52:09 AtHome systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Feb 26 13:52:09 AtHome systemd[1]: Started Advanced key-value store.
```

I see that file Can't open PID file not found above

But I have this file:

```
root@AtHome:/run/redis# ls -la
total 4
drwxr-sr-x  2 redis redis   60 Feb 26 14:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 38 root  root  1160 Feb 26 14:32 ..
-rw-rw----  1 redis redis    6 Feb 26 14:32 redis-server.pid
root@AtHome:/run/redis# cat redis-server.pid
22676
```

aand I got error on next command :

```
$ laravel-echo-server start
Error: The config file could not be found.
```

Is this errors as PID file was not found above?

How can it be fixed?

In composer.json :

```
"laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
"predis/predis": "^1.1",
```

**MODIFIED # :**
In /etc/redis/redis.conf I found

```
pidfile /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid
```

When I installed the ubuntu I installed /var on separate partition, so I have in /etc/fstab :

```
UUID=e531d8c5-530c-4533-a949-9fd5a62e0821 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sdb1 during installation

UUID=23cc34a1-2be9-43b1-9c79-8e53af7bc799 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /var was on /dev/sdb5 during installation

UUID=57c14b70-da85-4c5b-be6f-45174147d987 /var            ext4    defaults        0       2

that is why /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid looks like /run/redis/redis-server.pid in my console command.
```

I do not know can that be key of this problem? How can it be salved ?

**MODIFIED # 2 :**

1. Yes, redis started and it shows in status command :

   Active: active (running)

I see error message

```
Feb 26 13:52:09 AtHome systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid
```

I do not know how critical is it ?

2. I need to run in the root of my app laravel-echo-server for redis working

but I got error :

```
$ laravel-echo-server start
Error: The config file could not be found.
```

I suppose that 2) depends on 1), but not sure, I am new in redis and very common
knowledge about laravel-echo-server...

**MODIFIED # 3 :**
Searching how test redis I found how made tests, but looks like not all works properly :

```
app_root$  redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> set greetings "Hello World!" 
(error) NOAUTH Authentication required.
127.0.0.1:6379> get greetings 
(error) NOAUTH Authentication required.
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
app_root$ sudo systemctl restart redis
[sudo] password for serge: 
app_root$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> get greetings 
(error) NOAUTH Authentication required.
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

But I am still not sure if it is reason that I got error running laravel-echo-server

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, what problem? I'm not sure what the issue is here. The service says it's started.

Comment: please look at MODIFIED # 2 :

Comment: please look at MODIFIED # 3

Comment: This isn't a programming problem, it's off-topic here, so I'd suggest dealing with [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) which can help with getting Redis running properly.

Comment: Telling the truth I am not sure is that is problem with redis or with laravel-echo-server. Are there some additive checks to verify that